# jQuery - select the href in the next td

Tags: html, jquery

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense, hopefully this does:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href='url1'>Hyperlink 1</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 2
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href='url2'>Hyperlink 2</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to set the `onClick` event for the first `td` based on the `a` from the 2nd `td`.

My best attempt so far is:

```
$('tr td:first-of-type').attr('onClick', 'window.location = ' + $(this).next('td > a').attr('href'));
```

That line sets the `window.location` attribute but returns an undefined location:
`<td onclick="window.location = undefined">`

Any tips?

Comment: `.next('td > a')` is *actually* `.next().filter("td > a")` - now do you see why it doesn't work?  (at least, that part)

Comment: Your code is `var s = 'window.location = ' + $(this)....` `$('tr td:first-of-type').attr('onClick', s)`.  so what's `this` in the first part?

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is almost correct but there is a small issue with the context of $(this) within the .attr() function. You need to use a function callback to correctly reference the element you want. You can simplify the selector to directly target the 'a' element within the second 'td'. Like This:

```
$('tr td:first-of-type').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).next('td').find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: fwiw, this *can* be solved using .attr, but this is the "more better" option. The selector within .next() is only necessary if it's possible the next element isn't what you expect it to be, an often misunderstood fact about .next is that adding a selector *does not* cause it to go next until it finds a matching element, rather it only looks at the next sibling and then doesn't return anything if it doesn't match the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your logical mistake is here:

```
$(this).next('td > a')
```

Since `this` will be a `td`, `next('td > a')` is trying to find a **sibling** element `a` (since `td > a` will always select an `a`).

`a` though will never be a sibling of `td`. I know you're trying to mitigate this by providing the child selector `td > a` here, but that's not how it works:

> ## .next()
>
> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. **If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.**
> https://api.jquery.com/next/

Instead, I'd rather use this approach:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('a')
```

This approach is a little more robust than

```
$(this).next('td').find('a')
```

because it won't fail if you ever insert additional columns or the order of the table cells changes.

Comment: *Since this will be a td* - without checking, I'm not sure it will be in OPs code as it's not in an event handler (as provided), so `this` will be `window`

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to all answers and pointing out the mistake with using `this` and `.next()`.

After rethinking the problem, I used `.each()` to loop through the `td`'s .

```
$('tr td:first-of-type').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('onClick', 'window.location = \'' + $(this).next('td').find('a').attr('href')+'\'');
});
```

Comment: binding click events using attributes directly with javascript is.. a bit odd, given how much easier it is to just use the recommended method of binding events directly.